# OJET table length attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css, oracle, oracle-jet

I have recently started working on Oracle JET where I'm having a requirement of creating a table in which I have to populate the first three items or dataset from the api response data, I'm able to populate all the response data in the table but as I want to show the first three items only, is there any attribute which I can use to limit the dataset in the view?

Answer (score 0):

In [this](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=table&demo=basicTable) example from the cookbook, set the below shown attributes and Apply the changes.

```
scroll-policy-options='{"fetchSize":3}' style="height:200px"
```